# Router can't find a page in DurandalJS

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

Here's my router configuration:

```
        router.useConvention();

        router.mapRoute('error', 'viewmodels/error', "Error");

        router.mapNav('home');
        router.mapRoute('api', 'viewmodels/api', 'API Reference');
        router.mapRoute('set/:id', 'viewmodels/set', 'Set');
        router.mapRoute('folder/:id', 'viewmodels/folder', 'Folder');

        router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route, params) {
            //debugger;
            router.navigateTo('#/error');
        };

        logger.log('app has loaded :)', null, null, false);

        return router.activate('home');
```

I can find /api and other pages, but when I type in an invalid route, the chrome console gives me the following:

[image]

I have error.js and error.html just like the other pages.  It's in App/viewmodels/error.js, but I don't have to specify the folder with any other views/vms... why isn't it being found?

EDIT
Per Joseph's suggestion, I activated on "error" and I get this:

[image]

I'm so confused... why is it looking for error.js when it already found it in the correct location, and why does it think it's going to find an html document at that location?

I have a conventional file structure:

[image]

Comment: The code you posted works fine with a new project from the Durandal Starter Kit.  Is there any other place where the router is manipulated?

Comment: Just to make sure I searched my entire solution and I don't make any other calls to router... I have no idea what's causing it :/

Comment: There's strong clues in the fact that the route seems fine (you're not getting a "Route not found" error), but the resolved path is incorrect.  In my experience, that's usually a misconfiguration with router or with require.config.  You may want to try calling `router.activate('error');` instead of home, just to collect a data point on what happens.  If it bombs there, you can step through the router.js code to see where the difference is occurring.

Comment: @JosephGabriel Thanks - I just updated my post with the results of your suggestion.

Comment: What is your app.SetRoot set to?

Comment: In main.js it's set to 'viewmodels/intro', then I click "login" from my intro viewmodel - the only thing that does is app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell').  shell.js is where this routing config is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turn's out your issue is in **error.js** itself.  After requesting your files on Google Groups, I was able to duplicate problem.

Change this:

```
define(['services/dataservice'], function (dataservice) {
    var data = "error";
    return data;
})
```

to this:

```
define(['services/dataservice'], function (dataservice) {
    var data = "error";
    return {}
})
```

You were returning a string in which case Durandal assumes you are looking for a viewModel at the path given "/App/error.js".  You should be returning an object of some sort that you will use to bind your observables, etc.

Comment: Wow!  I've spent the whole day trying to figure this out.  Can't believe it.  Thanks so much mike.

Answer (score -1):

add this code:
router.mapRoute('pagenotfound', 'viewmodels/pagenotfound', 'page not found', false);